# sorting data from XML as numeric in a dataGridView

Tags: c#, xml, sorting, datagridview

This is my XML that is loaded into the dataGridView on load.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!--Game Scores-->
<Leaderboard Name="Nine">
  <Score>9</Score>
  <Difficulty>Normal</Difficulty>
  <Leaderboard Name="FourtyFour">
    <Score>44</Score>
    <Difficulty>Normal</Difficulty>
  </Leaderboard>
  <Leaderboard Name="Twelve">
    <Score>12</Score>
    <Difficulty>Normal</Difficulty>
  </Leaderboard>
  <Leaderboard Name="Sixer">
    <Score>6</Score>
    <Difficulty>Normal</Difficulty>
  </Leaderboard>
  <Leaderboard Name="Fifteen">
    <Score>15</Score>
    <Difficulty>Normal</Difficulty>
  </Leaderboard>  
</Leaderboard>
```

This Loads the XML and places it into the dataGridView

```
XmlDataDocument scorexml = new XmlDataDocument();             
        scorexml.DataSet.ReadXml(Application.StartupPath + "\\Leaderboard.xml");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = scorexml.DataSet;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "Leaderboard";
        dataGridView1.Columns["Name"].ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.Columns["Score"].ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.Columns["Difficulty"].ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Descending);
        dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>().ToList().ForEach(f => f.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable);
```

I removed all ability to sort manually and so the rows are not selectable.
It does sort the "Score" BUT it sorts it incorreclty as a string and not as a decimal and that is where my problem continues to taunt me.

For example the provided XML has 5 individual entries and are being sorted exactly like this

```
Score   Difficulty   Name
9         Normal     Nine
6         Normal     Sixer
44        Normal     FourtyFour
12        Normal     Twelve
15        Normal     Fifteen
```

But the desired sorting is the number from high to low. (hence the "leaderboard")

```
    Score   Difficulty   Name
    44        Normal     FourtyFour 
    15        Normal     Fifteen
    12        Normal     Twelve
    9         Normal     Nine
    6         Normal     Sixer
```

I have done a LOT of research throughout SO, Microsoft, CP and many other sites all which have had a basic similar problem although most of them was not using XML to load the data into it so the difference's are there.
I tried every possible fix for the problem provided by the other members for the OP and none of which has fixed my problem but it was a fix for most others that had the same similar problem. 
can anyone tell what it is that I am doing wrong or what it is that I need to convert it to decimal instead of a string since I know by default the dataGridView everything is a string.

links to other similar questions (proof of research)

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687407/how-to-sort-data-from-xml-as-numeric-in-a-datagrid) -- [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073594/c-sharp-datagridview-order-rows/1073625#1073625) -- [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17504306/datagridview-decimal-not-sorting) -- [Link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336046/how-to-sort-string-as-numbers-in-datagridview)

and MANY MANY More.

Comment: Try following : dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0].Select(x => int.Parse(x)), ListSortDirection.Descending);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a look and everything you have is excellent. There is one little change.

When you read the XML then InferTypedSchema; this will infer that Score is a numeric column.

```
scorexml.DataSet.ReadXml(Application.StartupPath + "\\Leaderboard.xml", XmlReadMode.InferTypedSchema);
```

The XML also has a little problem, the root node and first element are a little mixed up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Leaderboard>
  <Leaderboard Name="Nine">
    <Score>9</Score>
    <Difficulty>Normal</Difficulty>
  </Leaderboard>
  <Leaderboard Name="FourtyFour">
    <Score>44</Score>
    <Difficulty>Normal</Difficulty>
  </Leaderboard>
  <Leaderboard Name="Twelve">
    <Score>12</Score>
    <Difficulty>Normal</Difficulty>
  </Leaderboard>
  <Leaderboard Name="Sixer">
    <Score>6</Score>
    <Difficulty>Normal</Difficulty>
  </Leaderboard>
  <Leaderboard Name="Fifteen">
    <Score>15</Score>
    <Difficulty>Normal</Difficulty>
  </Leaderboard>
</Leaderboard>
```

Addition: The code and the research provided does not justify the Noob title you've given yourself. That's good work.

Comment: Thank you VERY much that did exactly what I was asking for and also thank you for the compliment.  I'm self taught and also very thorough.